# Mobile project based on CMake

Tags: android, c++, ios, cmake

I'm currently working on a project aimed to be ported both on Android and iOS.
Actually, it is a library written in *C++*, and we have a build system for the target platforms that is almost ready.

Despite the fact that it already works, it's quite complex and I was looking for something that can help in simplifying it.

I found the projects *[ios-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/)* and *[android-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/)* and thought that I could give them a try, but they look a bit abandoned and I'm not sure if it's worth it or there exists an alternative nowadays.

Did someone use them recently and can give me his feedback? It would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. What is about the Gradle? You saw it as a solution? Perhaps there is a plugin for xcode.

Comment: ?? I don't get you, what's about gradle? Neither our current build system nor the *ios/android-cmake* projects use it (at least, I think so).

Comment: more recent fork of ios-cmake: https://github.com/cristeab/ios-cmake, also the well-maintained https://github.com/ruslo/polly has toolchain files. I have no experience with either.

Comment: wow, *polly* looks very interesting indeed. thank you!!

Comment: For android nothing special should be needed, since android supports cmake files. For iOS you will need a custom toolchain file as mentioned above. Then use this to compile with cmake It will need some doing though until it works on both platforms.